# Splitting Author Name of Titlepage Over Two Lines When Using Smallcaps

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, document-classes, small-caps, author

I am using `\maketitle` and would like to split the author's name over two lines with an adjustable space in between.

I am also using small caps with `\author`, which seems to be causing a problem.

For instance, when I compile the following code with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[titlepage,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.25in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\textheight=4.75in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{microtype,scalefnt}
\date{}

\title{TITLE\\[-4pt] {\scalefont{0.45}{{\textit{OF THE}}}}\\[3pt] BOOK}
\author{The\\[3pt] Author}
%\author{{\scshape{The\\[3pt] Author}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I get what I want:

[image]

However, when I use the `author` command

`\author{{\scshape{The\\[3pt] Author}}}`

I get

[image]

with the error message

`[![enter image description here][3]][3]`

Notice that, despite the error message, the author's name is spread out over two lines, but with only the first line in small caps.

How should I specify small caps for the author, so that I may easily split the name over two lines with an adjustable vertical space between the two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.25in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\textheight=4.75in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{microtype,scalefnt}
\date{}

\title{TITLE\\[-4pt] {\scalefont{0.45}{{\textit{OF THE}}}}\\[3pt] BOOK}
\author{\textsc{The} \\[3pt]  \textsc{Author}}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: This seems to work quite nicely. Thank you.